# ng-form submitted an empty object but object should be modified

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

**Updated**

controller

```
chitchatApp.controller('chitchatCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.users = [

    {'username': 'John'},
    {'username': 'Dan'},
    {'username': 'Judy'}, 
    {'username': 'Michael'},
    {'username': 'Rebecca'},
    {'username': 'Macy'},
    {'username': 'Ross'}
    ];

    name = {'username': ''};
  //name = {}; 


    $scope.createuser = function createuser() { 
        $scope.users.push(name);
    };
}]);
```

html

```
<body ng-app="chitchatApp" ng-controller="chitchatCtrl">

<!-- users that are currently log on will be here -->
<div class="users_container">
    <div class="span2">
        Here are the users that are currently log in
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
            {{user.username}}
        </li>
    </div>
</div>

<form class="simple-form" ng-submit="createuser()">
Log in As: 
    <input type="text" ng-model="name.username">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>


</div>
</body>
```

---

This is a form I built in angular js

```
<form class="simple-form" ng-submit="createuser()">
Log in As: 
    <input type="text" ng-model="name.username">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

the ng-model is bind to an empty object in my controller

```
name = {};
```

I tried modifying it to this as well

```
name = {'username': ''};
```

I have a method on my $scope like this

```
$scope.createuser = function createuser() { 
        $scope.users.push(name);
    };
```

$scope.users is an array with objects and each object has the same property of 'username'

I am looping through the user in users using ng-repeat.

When I click submit, there is a new li but the content in the object disappeared. I don't have a database set up. Its pure javascript and angular js.

Is the model object in the form not getting modified
or 
Did I succeed but it disappeared right away, I noticed that when I push an object into an array (shows up with ng-repeat) then refresh then it disappears because its not persisted? I don't have db set up?

Comment: Please show the complete relevant parts of the controller and HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-model directive binds to properties of *$scope*. Therefore you'll need to make the *name* variable part of that scope using:

```
$scope.name = {'username': ''}; 

$scope.createuser = function createuser() { 
    var safeCopy = angular.copy($scope.name);
    $scope.users.push(safeCopy);
};
```

Comment: Eh? What do you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/94jZJ/3/ <-- that works find without it.

Comment: $scope.users.push(angular.copy($scope.name)); is necessary. Otherwise the bind will remain active, resulting in the modification of the newly inserted item.

Comment: @qwertynl Good point. Missed the part about *ng-model* implicitly defining the property on *$scope* if not defined already.

Comment: @Bart so in the end your answer does not _really_ answer anything. I am sorry :-( Weird though that the OPs code did not work fully. My answer made some minor modifications to make it so it _should_ work as expected.

Comment: I updated my code to check for an empty input @Bart http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/AvUzd/

Answer (score 1):

Try this out (sans local storage):

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [

    {
        'username': 'John'
    }, {
        'username': 'Dan'
    }, {
        'username': 'Judy'
    }, {
        'username': 'Michael'
    }, {
        'username': 'Rebecca'
    }, {
        'username': 'Macy'
    }, {
        'username': 'Ross'
    }];
    $scope.createuser = function createuser() {
        if ($scope.name && $scope.name.username && $scope.name.username.length) {
            $scope.users.push(angular.copy($scope.name));
        }
        $scope.name = {};
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<form class="simple-form" ng-submit="createuser()">Log in As:
    <input type="text" ng-model="name.username" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/AvUzd/

Comment: *ng-submit* cancels the default submit behavior of the form if no action attribute is present.